# Htaccess - Allow access to specific file only if specific referrer is set

Tags: php, .htaccess, referrer

Via .htaccess I want to allow access to a specific .php file only if accessed from a specific page on my domain.

What code would you use in .htaccess to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/allowed/page/url$
RewriteRule restricted\/page\.php - [NC,F]
```

Be reminded that the referrer in any HTTP request can be tricked easily.